# influx query to calculate success rate

Tags: sql, influxdb

I have the following data in influxdb.

```
time                count  http_status
----                -----  -----------
1532500250000000000 105058 200
1532500250000000000 11     499
1532500260000000000 108119 200
1532500260000000000 9      499
1532500260000000000 2      400
1532500270000000000 8      499
1532500270000000000 1      400
1532500270000000000 105321 200
1532500280000000000 1      400
1532500280000000000 106611 200
1532500280000000000 15     499
1532500290000000000 105572 200
1532500290000000000 9      499
1532500290000000000 5      400
```

the http_status is my api status.

I want to create one continuous query on this measurement to generate success rate of my api, which should be calculate as the following

```
count(http_status == 200) / count(all apis)
```

I know the logic is simple. But I failed to write one influx sql to generate this. So I am writing here for help.

Thanks in advance.